# How to run .net unit tests in Docker without installing the whole SDK?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

Is there a way to run .net unit tests (xunit or others) in Docker without installing the whole SDK?

I would like to have a minimal Docker image that would be use exclusively to run my tests.

Comment: Why is that too broad ? Basically the question is: It it possible to run .Net tests without having the Sdk installed.

Answer (score 3):

No. Running tests requires the SDK. However, it is possible to use layers to remove this dependency from the final image. For example, if your ultimate goal was to have just the running app, but you wanted to build and test inside the container first before running it, then you could do:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
# do your build, test, publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
# copy published files from build-env
```

In the end, your image would just reference the ASP.NET Core runtime, not the SDK. It should be noted, though, that this will run your tests when creating the image in the first place, not each time the container runs. That should actually be sufficient, though, since if the tests passed during the build, the published app in the final image will work as well. There's really no need to test it over and over. However, if you're wanting an image devoted entirely to testing, then you'll need to build off the SDK image.

Comment: So there is no way to execute tests if you only have the dotnet core runtime installed? I mean, would it be possible to build tests on a host that has the sdk installed and then run them on a host that only has the runtime?

Comment: No. Testing requires the SDK.

Comment: However, it's unclear what you're trying to achieve here. Testing is part of the build/CI pipeline. You don't release code that needs to be tested, for fairly obvious reasons. As such, there's no need to run tests on a deployed app, and there's no need to stick to a runtime image if it's not being deployed.

Comment: I understand. We have tests that requires to have a lot of installed dependencies. We are trying to reduce the size of the Docker images that are running those tests. That got us into asking ourselves if it was possible to run tests with the runtime only. 

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That's the part I'm a little confused on. It doesn't make sense really to have "testing" images. The running of the tests should simply be a stage of your Dockerfile. Then, you would publish, and copy that publish output into your final stage which would derive from the runtime only. The final image would only include that last stage (i.e. the tested and compiled application, ready to go, with just the ASP.NET Core runtime). The layers from the previous stages would be discarded.